# How do i pass a value from a controller A to a view (a) and then from view (a) to a controller B?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, view, viewdata

I have a field type of nvarchar in my sql table which is Availablsizes, the values are like 40,41,42,43. I would like to split these strings in controller A with `.split()` method then pass it to view a in a drop down list as a single select list. the from the view (a) I'd like to pass the selected value let suppose value 42 to the B controller, how should I do that? I wasn't able to write a single code for this because I don't know how to do it? Any realistic example would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you provide a code sample ?

Comment: @Vladimir don't know really how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

So first you can create a view model that would hold both the choices and the chosen value.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        SizeChoices = new List<int>();
    }

    public int ChosenSize { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> SizeChoices { get; set; }

    public SelectList SizeChoicesSelectList
    {
        get
        {
            return new SelectList(SizeChoices);
        }
    }
}
```

In `ControllerA` you would need to construct this view model and pass it to the `View` method.

```
public ActionResult ViewA()
{
    var sizeChoicesFromDb = "40,41,42,43"; // get from db

    var myModel = new MyViewModel
    {
        SizeChoices = sizeChoicesFromDb .Split(',').ToList().ConvertAll(Int32.Parse)
    };

    return View(myModel);
}
```

Then, in the view of `ControllerA`, you can render the dropdown using the `Html.DropDownListFor` method. You would need to wrap this in a `Html.BeginForm` statement that posts to `ActionB` of `ControllerB`.

```
@model So_MVC.Models.MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionB", "ControllerB", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ChosenSize, Model.SizeChoicesSelectList)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Then in `ActionB` of `ControllerB` you would need to pass in `MyViewModel` as a parameter to the action method.

```
public ActionResult ActionB(MyViewModel myViewModel)
{
    // myViewModel.ChosenSize will contain whatever you chose

    // ... 
}
```